# Matrix manipulation instead of loops

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I have the following matrix form $[J]$:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \{ v[3],p + v[2]\}\\
        \{v[3], p + v[2], 2 p + v[1]\} \\
        \{v[3], p + v[2],2 p + v[1], 3 p + v[0]\}\\
        \{v[3], p + v[2],2 p + v[1], 3 p + v[0]\}  \\
        \vdots
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to operate the list of each row by Max and Integrate and then add them all together like this:

$H=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \max \{ v[3],p + v[2]\}dF(p)+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \max \{v[3], p + v[2], 2 p + v[1]\}dF(p)+\dots$

I would like to use matrix operations to do it instead of loops, but I can't find a way to make it work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you know each `v[i]` values; `Total[Integrate[Max[#], {p, 0,  Infinity}] & /@ J]`  ?

Comment: all except the last one, from H I will solve the last value v[3]

Comment: I see. Can you post actual vector values if it is not too long. What is the length of `J`?

Comment: I couldn't by pass the code formatting thing here is a link with a picture of J with n=10, at some point I would want to go for n=100 [Matrix](https://imgur.com/a/LiVkk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of Okkes works, this do the job

```
Total[Integrate[Max[#], {p, 0, Infinity}] & /@ J]
```

Thanks!